# Removing extra commas from C# constructor

Tags: c#

Here's what I've got, I need to keep the console from returning additional commas on the main program, so I probably need to rewrite string e. Month, description etc. should still have commas, but if something like "note" is absent, those additional commas would be gone.

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string e = description + ", " + month + day + year + ", " + amount.ToString("C") + ", ";
            e = e + paymentMethod + ", " +  trip + ", " + note;

        return e;

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean "remove commas"? What is your expected output?

Comment: So you can modify the `ExpenseItem` implementation? Well, then just implement `ToString` different. You may want to get a bit clearer on your question.

Comment: @Kobi, just to remove the extra commas from the output from ToString.

Comment: I'm not sure that the constructor has anything to do with your ToString() formatting. Also, have a look at String.Format http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx. It gives better control over the formatting of dates, numbers etc and will also avoid string catenation.

Comment: As a side note, there are many features of C# you seem to be missing - like [auto implemented  properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) - `public Description {get;set;}`, and [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx), instead of the second constructor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this, to filter out empty elements:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string[] elements = new string[] { description, 
                String.Concat(month, day, year),
                amount.ToString("C"), paymentMethod, trip, note };

    return String.Join(", ", elements.Where(s => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
}
```

A little more verbose option, but also less confusing and C# 2 compatible:

```
private static void AddIfNotNull(List<string> elements, string value)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        elements.Add(value);
}

public override string ToString()
{
    List<string> elements = new List<string>();
    AddIfNotNull(elements, description);
    elements.Add(String.Concat(month, day, year));
    elements.Add(amount.ToString("C"));
    AddIfNotNull(elements, paymentMethod);
    AddIfNotNull(elements, trip);
    AddIfNotNull(elements, note);
    return String.Join(", ", elements.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite `ToString` like this, is that what you want?

```
public override string ToString()
{
    string e = description + " " + month + day + year + " " + 
        amount.ToString("C") + " ";
    e = e + paymentMethod + " " +  trip + " " + note;

    return e;
}
```